# Implement blur for camera preview android

Tags: java, android, android-camera, blur

I want to implement lens blur function for camera preview (I am using surfaceview). In this function, there will be a circle at the point user clicked, inside circle is normal preview, and outside preview is blurred. Like Camera360:

[Camera 360](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKLES.jpg)

All blur library on Github now is just applied for bitmap. There is only one library for camera preview

https://github.com/NateWickstrom/BlurryCamera

But this library use imageview to capture each frame of camera and then blur it and set to imageview. This way is so lag.

Does anyone know how to implement blur with circle transparent for camera preview preview, or at least blur camera preview ? (I will find someway to add circle transparent)

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you got any solution??